# Recover Byte array from JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a byte array in my `JSON` and I want to recover it.

**Java Code**

```
String client = ui.ReturnJSon();            
ArrayList<JSONObject> vetor = ArrayJson(client);                    
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ui, vetor.size()); // print 56 (that's right)                     
int client_Id = vetor.get(0).get("Cliente_Id");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ui, client_Id); // print 1414509 (that's right)

byte[] template = (byte[])vetor.get(0).get("template");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ui, template.length); // Doesn't appear any Dialog
```

How can I get a byte array comming from my JSON ?

**Model Layer**

```
public class lb
{
    public byte[] template { set; get; }
    public byte[] template2 { set; get; }
    public byte[] template3 { set; get; }
    public int Client_Id { set; get; }
}
```

**JSON Sample**

```
    [{"template":[167,255,1,30,17,1,204,0,1,237,0,128,0],
"template2":[167,255,1,30,17,1,204,0,1,237,0,128,0,171,0,1,31],
"template3":null,
"Cliente_Id":1414509},
```

Comment: If you used Jackson, this might work of the bat. Right now you have to do custom diserialization. Split the `[]` into Strings and use `Byte.parseByte()` on each element, then add them to an array.

Comment: No need to do parseByte -- the numbers will be Bytes or Integers in the resulting array.  You just need to do `templateArray[i].byteValue()` on each element.

Comment: @HotLicks but how I'll recover the array from JSon ? 

I've tryied `byte[] template = (byte[])vetor.get(0).get("template");`

Comment: "template" will be some sort of Java List object -- which type depends on what deserializer you use.  You can access the elements from that using, probably, get(i), then get the actual byte value from the resulting Integer or whatever with byteValue().  Use your debugger to figure out what you have!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh!

```
List template = vetor.get(0).get("template");
byte[] byteArray = new byte[template.size];
For (int i = 0; i < template.size; i++) {
    byteArray[i] = template.get(i).byteValue();
}
```